# Per Call mode of Instance Management in WCF not working

Tags: c#, wcf

I have done a fairly simple sample to demonstrate Per Call mode of Instance Management.
I have used a static variable counter to increment the count for each instance and I have assigned the instance mode as perCall. The expected behavior of the count variable should the value should not get incremented, as the instance is disposed as for every request, But the observed behavior is that the counter variable is incremented continuously for every request and even for new clients.

This is my Service Code

```
namespace PerCallInstanceService 
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService 
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int MyMethod();

    }
}

namespace PerCallInstanceService 
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class MyService :IMyService
    {
        public int m_Counter=0;

        #region IMyService Members

        public int MyMethod()
        {
           m_Counter++;
           return m_Counter;
        }


        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is the Client Side Code.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Service Instance mode: Per-Call");

 Console.WriteLine("Client  making call to service...");

 MyServiceClient proxy = new MyServiceClient();

 Console.WriteLine("Counter:" + proxy.MyMethod());

 Console.WriteLine("Counter:" + proxy.MyMethod());

 Console.WriteLine("Counter:" + proxy.MyMethod());

 Console.WriteLine("Counter:" + proxy.MyMethod());

 Console.ReadLine();
```

My ServiceHost:

Comment: (InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerSession) will retain session state unless proxy.Close()/Abort is called.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, It's actually InstanceContextMode.PerCall. I have the above problem with PerCall Mode. Edited the above..

Comment: Could you post the code where you create the ServiceHost?

Comment: <%@ ServiceHost Debug="true" Language="C#" Service="PerCallInstanceService.MyService" CodeBehind="~/PerCallInstanceService.MyService.cs" %>                                                                         Thats my ServiceHost file. If that's what you asked.

Comment: Even I have the same problem, can you get me a solution? I'm referring this article --> http://wcftutorial.net/Per-Call-Service.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you must be using InstanceContextMode.PerCall not InstanceContextMode.PerSession

Comment: Sorry for the typo, It's actually InstanceContextMode.PerCall. I have the above problem with PerCall Mode.

Comment: code looks all ok, please check your deployment, i.e your client is pointing to updated service

Comment: Up ? Did you find a solution ? I'm on the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your question states,"I have used a **static** variable counter to increment the count", but your code doesn't have a static variable. 
However, if you are using static then the counter is going to go on increasing even though it is PerCall and in spite of the object being recreated on every call . The static variable stays out of your object's instance that is created every time a call is made. Once an object is created, the corresponding static variable will stay in memory till the assembly is unloaded.